# Can't center image in CSS border

Tags: css

I am trying to add a small border to an icon.

The problem is, the image is in the top of bordered box, but I want it to display in the center. Here is what it looks like at present

[image: my icon]

My border CSS style:

```
div.Icon{
    float:left;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    padding:3px;
    height:80px;
    width:110px;
    }

div.Icon img{
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center the image in the div as its background.

```
div.Icon{
    float:left;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    padding:3px;
    height:80px;
    width:110px;
    background:url(yourimage.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

...And if the image has to be dynamic, you could set the `background-image` directly in the `style` attribute of you element in your html.

```
<div style="background-image:url(<?php //whatever ?>);"></div>
```

In the css, you can then just remove the path...

```
background:no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

Comment: Hello Leandre , i am using it in php for diffrant icons , i can't use it as background , thank you ..

Comment: Or he could just add the border to the image itself instead of a div?  Either way, I'm lost as to why this question is still open.

Comment: Lendre_B << thank you it's now working fine ,, Dave << i am sorry this is first time i make question here , and i don't understand this site , and my english is too bad ! but finally it's fixed and thank you all , i will try to close this question fastly !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just setting the border to the image itself instead of a div wrapping around the image?:

```
img.icon {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

Then you wouldn't need to set the height and width in CSS and you wouldn't need to wrap an unnecessary div around the image.

Comment: Hello Dave , its work fine , but the image is display in homepage of website they should be border one size !

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand what you just said. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding =)

```
div.Icon img {
text-align:center;
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Hello Trey it's not one image size , and not one image , i have big images , if i added this padding , big images will display out box !